# Problem deploying website to Netlify keep getting errors. I have tried multiple build commands

Tags: netlify

Github repo [https://github.com/NaveenJc10/Naveen]
Could someone please help me to solve this issue. Thank you

12:07:21 PM: Build ready to start
12:07:23 PM: build-image version: 0582042f4fc261adc7bd8333f34884959c577302
12:07:23 PM: build-image tag: v3.7.6
12:07:23 PM: buildbot version: cb3d235979bae64f617d34524cb2e8a9de68153f
12:07:23 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
12:07:23 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
12:07:23 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
12:07:24 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
12:07:24 PM: git clone https://github.com/NaveenJc10/Naveen
12:07:25 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
12:07:25 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
12:07:27 PM: Starting build script
12:07:27 PM: Installing dependencies
12:07:27 PM: Python version set to 2.7
12:07:28 PM: v12.18.0 is already installed.
12:07:29 PM: Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
12:07:29 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
12:07:29 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
12:07:29 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
12:07:31 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.1
12:07:31 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
12:07:31 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
12:07:31 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
12:07:31 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.14.4
12:07:47 PM: > deasync@0.1.21 install /opt/build/repo/node_modules/deasync
12:07:47 PM: > node ./build.js
12:07:47 PM: linux-x64-node-12 exists; testing
12:07:47 PM: Binary is fine; exiting
12:07:47 PM: > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/core-js
12:07:47 PM: > node -e “try{require(’./postinstall’)}catch(e){}”
12:07:47 PM: > parcel-bundler@1.12.4 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/parcel-bundler
12:07:47 PM: > node -e “console.log(’\u001b[35m\u001b[1mLove Parcel? You can now donate to our open collective:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n > \u001b[34mhttps://opencollective.com/parcel/donate\u001b[0m’)”
12:07:47 PM: Love Parcel? You can now donate to our open collective:
12:07:47 PM: > Contribute to Parcel - Open Collective
12:07:48 PM: npm WARN Naveen@1.0.0 No description
12:07:48 PM: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/fsevents):
12:07:48 PM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {“os”:“darwin”,“arch”:“any”} (current: {“os”:“linux”,“arch”:“x64”})
12:07:48 PM: added 766 packages from 461 contributors and audited 768 packages in 15.721s
12:07:48 PM: 46 packages are looking for funding
12:07:48 PM: run npm fund for details
12:07:48 PM: found 68 vulnerabilities (67 moderate, 1 high)
12:07:48 PM: run npm audit fix to fix them, or npm audit for details
12:07:48 PM: NPM modules installed
12:07:49 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
12:07:49 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
12:07:49 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
12:07:49 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
12:07:49 PM: Installing missing commands
12:07:49 PM: Verify run directory
12:07:51 PM: ​
12:07:51 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:07:51 PM: Netlify Build
12:07:51 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:07:51 PM: ​
12:07:51 PM: ❯ Version
12:07:51 PM: @netlify/build 11.18.1
12:07:51 PM: ​
12:07:51 PM: ❯ Flags
12:07:51 PM: deployId: 60ac77f9aa712200a9963afb
12:07:51 PM: ​
12:07:51 PM: ❯ Current directory
12:07:51 PM: /opt/build/repo
12:07:51 PM: ​
12:07:51 PM: ❯ Config file
12:07:51 PM: No config file was defined: using default values.
12:07:51 PM: ​
12:07:51 PM: ❯ Context
12:07:51 PM: production
12:07:51 PM: ​
12:07:51 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:07:51 PM: 1. Build command from Netlify app
12:07:51 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:07:51 PM: ​
12:07:51 PM: $ parcel build --no-minify index.html
12:07:53 PM: :rotating_light: /opt/build/repo/images/logo.svg: Invalid Version: undefined
12:07:53 PM: at new SemVer (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/semver/semver.js:314:11)
12:07:53 PM: at compare (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/semver/semver.js:647:10)
12:07:53 PM: at lt (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/semver/semver.js:688:10)
12:07:53 PM: at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:274:22
12:07:53 PM: at Object.default (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:22:12)
12:07:53 PM: at getEnvPlugins (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/transforms/babel/env.js:62:34)
12:07:53 PM: at getEnvConfig (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/transforms/babel/env.js:12:25)
12:07:53 PM: at async getBabelConfig (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/transforms/babel/config.js:32:19)
12:07:53 PM: at async babelTransform (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/transforms/babel/transform.js:6:16)
12:07:53 PM: at async JSAsset.pretransform (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/assets/JSAsset.js:83:5)
12:07:54 PM: ​
12:07:54 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:07:54 PM: “build.command” failed
12:07:54 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:07:54 PM: ​
12:07:54 PM: Error message
12:07:54 PM: Command failed with exit code 1: parcel build --no-minify index.html
12:07:54 PM: ​
12:07:54 PM: Error location
12:07:54 PM: In Build command from Netlify app:
12:07:54 PM: parcel build --no-minify index.html
12:07:54 PM: ​
12:07:54 PM: Resolved config
12:07:54 PM: build:
12:07:54 PM: command: parcel build --no-minify index.html
12:07:54 PM: commandOrigin: ui
12:07:54 PM: publish: /opt/build/repo/dist
12:07:54 PM: functions:
12:07:54 PM: ‘*’: {}
12:07:54 PM: Caching artifacts
12:07:54 PM: Started saving node modules
12:07:54 PM: Finished saving node modules
12:07:54 PM: Started saving build plugins
12:07:54 PM: Finished saving build plugins
12:07:54 PM: Started saving pip cache
12:07:54 PM: Finished saving pip cache
12:07:54 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
12:07:54 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
12:07:54 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
12:07:54 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
12:07:54 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
12:07:54 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
12:07:54 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
12:07:54 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
12:07:54 PM: Started saving go dependencies
12:07:54 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
12:07:57 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
12:07:57 PM: Creating deploy upload records
12:07:57 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
12:07:57 PM: Failed during stage ‘building site’: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
12:07:57 PM: Finished processing build request in 33.980133128s

Answer (score 1):

Your html file should be index.html. The second reason, if your app is builded with react you should create also built file